# 2 thread parallel in linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process, glib

I just begin to implement thread. I want create 1 main thread and 2 thread running parallel.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define THREAD1 1
#define THREAD2 2

GMainLoop *loop1;
GMainLoop *loop2;

pthread_t pth1; // this is our thread identifier
pthread_t pth2; // this is our thread identifier

gboolean timeout_callback1(gpointer data){
    clock_t start = clock();
    int msec = start * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("timeout_callback ==== 1 at %d seconds %d milliseconds\n", msec/1000, msec%1000);
}

gboolean timeout_callback2(gpointer data){
    sleep(2);
    clock_t start = clock();
    int msec = start * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("timeout_callback ==== 2 at %d seconds %d milliseconds\n", msec/1000, msec%1000);
}

/* This is our thread function.  It is like main(), but for a thread */
void *threadFunc(void *arg)
{
    int *index;
    int i = 0;

    index=(int*)arg;

if (index == THREAD1){
    printf("threadFunc: %d\n", index);
    loop1 = g_main_loop_new ( NULL , FALSE );
    //add source to default context
    g_timeout_add (100 , timeout_callback1 , loop1); 
    g_main_loop_run (loop1);
    g_main_loop_unref(loop1);
} else {
    if (index == THREAD2){
        printf("threadFunc: %d\n", index);
        loop2 = g_main_loop_new ( NULL , FALSE );
        //add source to default context
        g_timeout_add (100 , timeout_callback2 , loop2); 
        g_main_loop_run (loop2);
        g_main_loop_unref(loop2);
    }else
        printf("index not support\n");
}

return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    /* Create worker thread */
    pthread_create(&pth1,NULL,threadFunc,THREAD1);
    pthread_create(&pth2,NULL,threadFunc,THREAD2);

    /* wait for our thread to finish before continuing */

    while(1)
    {
        usleep(1);
        //printf("main() is running...\n");
        //++i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

command build:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include thread.c -o thread -lglib-2.0 -lpthread
```

result:

```
threadFunc: 2
threadFunc: 1
timeout_callback ==== 1 at 0 seconds 2 milliseconds
timeout_callback ==== 2 at 0 seconds 72 milliseconds
timeout_callback ==== 1 at 0 seconds 72 milliseconds
timeout_callback ==== 2 at 0 seconds 142 milliseconds
timeout_callback ==== 1 at 0 seconds 142 milliseconds
timeout_callback ==== 2 at 0 seconds 218 milliseconds
timeout_callback ==== 1 at 0 seconds 218 milliseconds
timeout_callback ==== 2 at 0 seconds 283 milliseconds
timeout_callback ==== 1 at 0 seconds 283 milliseconds
timeout_callback ==== 2 at 0 seconds 348 milliseconds
timeout_callback ==== 1 at 0 seconds 348 milliseconds
timeout_callback ==== 2 at 0 seconds 421 milliseconds
```

this result is'n like as my expect. I think **timeout_callback1** is called more times **timeout_callback2** because in fucntion **timeout_callback2 has sleep(2);**

Could you help me explain for me about result?
And Pleas give me some advice how to timeout_callback1 run with independence timeout_callback2 ?

Thank you so much.

Comment: `clock()` measure only CPU time for the whole process. `sleep()` doesn't consume any CPU. What do you want to measure exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read `g_timeout_add` documentation here:
https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add you can find that:

> This internally creates a main loop source using g_timeout_source_new() and attaches it to the global GMainContext

And from GMainContex here:https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GMainContext

> The GMainContext struct is an opaque data type representing a set of sources to be handled in a main loop.

And furthermore:

> GMainContext can only be running in a single thread, but sources can
>   be added to it and removed from it from other threads.

Therefore it actually makes sense since both the `THREAD1` and `THREAD2` will be calling `g_timeout_add()` at the same rate.

Comment: first of all, thanks for your respond. I don't use gmainloop for each thread and use while(1): if (index == THREAD1){
  //printf("threadFunc: %d\n", index);
  while(1){
   usleep(1);
   printf("threadFunc: %d\n", index);
  } and result is well. Thank is advice